# Where just if both parameters aren't null

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

Just fill with `Where` clause if both parameters of my stored procedure aren't null.

### The problem

Take a look in the following query fragment:

```
If(userEmail Is Not Null Or userMarketId Is Not Null)
    Where 
        Then
        Case When 
            userEmail = '' 
        Then user.MarketId = userMarketId
        Else user.Email = userEmail
        End = 1
End If;
```

The syntax is wrong — was just for illustration — but the context is exactly what I'm thinking about.

What can I do to reach my goal, guys? I mean, what is the right syntax to perform what I want to do?

### The scenario

Okay, it seems that something is not clear here and I will explain a little bit more.

> If the first parameter of the procedure (`userEmail`) is filled, then my `Where` clause will be based on `userEmail`.
>
> If the second parameter of the procedure (`userMarketId`) is filled, then my `Where` clause will be based on `userMarketId`.
>
> If both of my parameters are empty, then there's not a `Where` clause.
>
> (Both parameters filled will never happen)

In other words, or one parameter, or another, or no one.

### Situation

This procedure is called `getUsers`. It is invoked if the user performs an authentication on the application and it retrieves the user's information.

Case the user is an administrator, then he have access to a list of users registered on the application. To get this *list of users*, I'm using the same query because the columns that I want to get is the same of a single user.

To separate the proposals of the query, I think that I need to use `Case`/`If` to "play" with (stored procedure's) parameters.

### Code spotlight

Follow the full stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
   Select user.Id as userId, 
               userPersonal.Firstname as userFirstname, 
               userPersonal.Lastname as userLastname
    From app_users as user
    If(userEmail Is Not Null Or userMarketId Is Not Null)
        Where 
            Then
            Case When 
                userEmail = '' 
            Then user.MarketId = userMarketId
            Else user.Email = userEmail
            End = 1
    End If;
END
```

### Technical detail

I'm using `MySQL`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be exactly the same as just tagging the 2 null checks to the end of the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Why are you trying to do assignments inside a where clause? Is this an update statement? Please add more code and example data with expected results. You ask us what you can do to reach your goal, *but you don't tell us what the goal is*. Stating what you want to do (in English, not code) would clarify this question a lot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is all within a `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT` -- he wants to have a conditional `WHERE` clause, required (or changing form) based on stored values.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Take a look on my last update. :-)

Comment: @Guilherme Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with operator short-circuiting:

```
WHERE (userEmail IS NOT NULL AND user.Email=userEmail) OR (userMarketID IS NOT NULL AND user.MarketID = userMarketId)
```

I believe will have the effect you're looking for.  The only issue would be your failure mode (both null; both not null) cases, and how to twist the logic to make those work the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you really just want to use an or statement.

```
where 
(
   (userEmail is null and userMarketID=user.marketID) OR --Handles when useremail is blank
   (userMarketID is null and userEmail = user.email) OR --handles when usermarketID is blank
   (useremail is not null and usermarketID is not null and user.email=useremail) --Handles when neither are blank
  --example doesn't illustrate a need for a where when both are blank.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to filter rows as follows:

- If the `userEmail` parameter has a value (isn't null/empty), filter by `user.Email`.
- If `userEmail` *is* null/empty but `userMarketId` isn't then filter by `user.MarketId`.

If that's the case, this should work:

```
WHERE (COALESCE(userEmail, '') <> '' AND user.Email = userEmail)
   OR (COALESCE(userMarketID, '') <> '' AND user.MarketId = userMarketId)
```

If this answer doesn't work (and if any of the others doesn't work), please post the entire query. My answer is a best guess at your requirements, and that may be the case for the others as well.

Comment: Almost there, @EdGibbs. Your "philosophy" about my problem are right, but I think the syntax aren't. When I fill the first parameter with user's email, nothing happens. Actually, the query returns me a list of users whose `userMarketId` is equal than zero (`0`). I've updated the main topic with more details to help you help me.

Comment: Why the `COALESCE(var, '') <> ''` idiom, compared to the `var IS NOT NULL` idiom?  Is it because you want a simultaneous `var IS NOT NULL AND var <> ''` test?

Comment: @zebediah49 - yes, I'm trying for `var IS NOT NULL AND var <> ''`. I used the `COALESCE` purely because it was less typing :)

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - are the `userMarketID` parameter and the `user.MarketId` column numeric? Also, when you filled the first parameter with the user's email, did you specify a value for the second parameter?